# WS_EX_COMPOSITED causes endless repainting when restoring form from minimize state

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

The `Form` takes endless time to repaint when restoring from minimize state.
The `Form` is borderless. I'm overriding **WndProc** and **CreateParms**.
I'm restoring the borderless `Form` from minimized state to normal state.
I'm Overriding **CreateParms** method to drop shadow and stop flickering.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

            m_aeroEnabled = CheckAeroEnabled();
            if (!m_aeroEnabled)
               cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;

            cp.Style |= WS_MINIMIZEBOX;             
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; //WS_EX_COMPOSITED                
            cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DBLCLKS;

            return cp;
        }
    }
```

The problem disappears when removing  **cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000** but then there is a flickering problem.

**Edit:**
Adding the code of the custom control that seems is causing the problem:

```
public partial class BorderPanel : Panel
{
    public BorderPanel()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(pe.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, 
           BorderColor, borderSize.Left, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
           BorderColor, borderSize.Top, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
           BorderColor, borderSize.Right, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
           BorderColor, borderSize.Bottom, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Raymond Chen on this: [WS_EX_COMPOSITED](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171018-00/?p=97245) (read the comments). Also: [Can someone explain WS_EX_COMPOSITED](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca0e6cc1-8e03-4dfc-832d-0a7a6ae38d56/can-someone-explain-wsexcomposited?forum=vcgeneral) (`nobugz` wasn't there, weird. Maybe he's here).

Comment: You are doing something weird probably

Comment: I'm here.  The only rapid repaint problem I've seen over the years is with TabControl having too many tabs and displaying the scroll widget.  Having an issue with a restore is very unusual, it just isn't very different from what happens to a window when it is first displayed.  Recommended debugging technique is to set the Visible property of the controls in the form to False one by one to find the troublemaker.

Comment: @HansPassant I have a custom control (panel with borders) seems it's causing the problem and I also noticed that the panels are drawn but transparent. I'll add the code of the custom control above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem like you and i solved this changing TrasnsparencyKey in form design from black to another color but not black, try one color that you are not using.