# After minimizing the Windows Form in vb.net, if i click the icon in the taskbar to reload the form, it is taking very long time to reload

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows form, called "Home page". when users open the tool this form will load in full screen. I made `FormBorderStyle` as `None` and `Window State` as `Maximized`.

And I kept one label with text as '-', so when the user clicks on it the form will get minimized, below is the code.

```
Private Sub lbl_Min_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbl_Min.Click
     Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

Now after minimizing the screen, when I click the icon of the tool in the task bar, the form is not loading fully, only some portions of the form will load. Now instead of clicking that minimize, if I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and switch between the windows or else if I try <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (This will show the desktop) and then if I click the icon of the tool in the task bar, the form will load within seconds. Even when the tool opens for the 1st time, the form will load within a seconds. So I need other option so that this issue will be resolved.

Comment: How do you open the window again. With `Me.Show()` or `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal` ?

Comment: @MarcoSadowski I am not using anything to restore the window. When I minimize the window the icon anyways will be there in the taskbar since I am not hiding the form, so when I click on that icon the window should open in full screen, For ex: When we are working in Microsoft Word if we minimize it the icon will be there in the taskbar, so when we click on it, the word will open in full screen.

Comment: I noticed one thing, I am using below code to stop flickering of the form
    `Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or 33554432
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property`

Comment: `Private Sub PreVentFlicker()
        With Me
            .SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
            .SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
            .SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
            .UpdateStyles()
        End With
    End Sub`

So if I comment these code the minimized form will load after few seconds, but if I comment one problem is the form will flicker while loading for the first time and it will flicker even when I restore the minimized form to maximized

Comment: I guess it is similar to this one [WS_EX_COMPOSITED causes endless repainting when restoring form from minimize state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349886/ws-ex-composited-causes-endless-repainting-when-restoring-form-from-minimize-sta#comment89672875_51349886)

Comment: Dont post so much code in your comments, it is unreadable, just edit your question

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε but where is the solution to this issue. Please post the reference link only if it has a solution. And that too my question is related to vb.net, not C#. And related to so much code in my comment section will take this point into consideration

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint:="ReleaseCapture")>
    Private Shared Sub ReleaseCapture()
    End Sub
    <DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint:="SendMessage")>
    Private Shared Sub SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer)
    End Sub
    Private Sub panelTitleBar_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown, PanelTitleBar.MouseDown
        ReleaseCapture()
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, &H112, &HF012, 0)
    End Sub
  
  'Minimize borderless form from taskbar
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.Style = cp.Style Or &H20000 '<--- Minimize borderless form from taskbar
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).